# linked list first node to be the last

Tags: c, list, linked-list, stack, push

For Example: I have a linked list: 4->1->0->2->3 and then i want to rotate my list and get this output: 1->0->2->3->4, the first node to be a last node. But when i'm trying to make this i get out this result: 1->0->2->3->0->4. What happend i could not debug it.

```
#ifndef HEADER_PUSH_SWAP_H
# define HEADER_PUSH_SWAP_H

# include "../libft/libft.h"
# include "../ft_printf/include/ft_printf.h"

typedef struct s_stack
{
    int n;
    struct s_stack *next;
} Stack;


typedef struct s_actions
{
    void (*pa)(Stack **a, Stack **b);
    void (*pb)(Stack **a, Stack **b);
    void (*sa)(Stack **a, Stack *x);
    void (*sb)(Stack **b, Stack *x);
    void (*ss)(Stack **a, Stack *x, Stack **b, Stack *y);
    void (*ra)(Stack **a);
    void (*rb)(Stack **b);
    void (*rr)(void);
    void (*rra)(void);
    void (*rrb)(void);
    void (*rrr)(void);
} Actions;

typedef struct s_important
{
    int size;
    int length;
    int  *collection_of_ints;
    char *collection;
    char **split;
    int a_len;
    int b_len;
} t_important;


Actions init(void);

//parser functions
void stack_nums_counter(char **av, t_important *data);
void collect(char **av, t_important *data);
void store(Stack **a, t_important *data);

//Helpers
void __collecting_ints(t_important *data);
void __sorted__indacies(t_important *data);
void ___bubble___(int *arrtmp, int length);
void __store__(t_important *data);
int is_sorted(int *ints, int len);
int __repeats__(t_important *data);
int __check__collection(t_important *data);
//Error functions
int errno(char *err);

//sorting algorithm functions
void __sort_a__(Stack **a, Stack **b, t_important *data, Actions action);
void pa(Stack **a, Stack **b);
void pb(Stack **a, Stack **b);
void sa(Stack **a, Stack *x);
void sb(Stack **b, Stack *x);
void ss(Stack **a, Stack *x, Stack **b, Stack *y);
void ra(Stack **a);
void rb(Stack **b);
void rr(void);
void rra(void);
void rrb(void);
void rrr(void);
int check_stack_length(Stack *stack);
#endif
```

Store Function to store data in nodes. It was called in main function before sort_a() function

```
void store(Stack **a, t_important *data)
{
    int i;
    Stack *tmp;

    tmp = *a;
    (*a)->next = tmp;
    i = 0;
    while(i < data->length)
    {
        tmp->n = data->collection_of_ints[i];
        tmp->next = malloc(sizeof(Stack));
        tmp = tmp->next;
        i++;
    }
    tmp->next = NULL;
}
```

Main Function In where i call **sort_a**() function on the last line of code.

```
#include "../includes/header_push_swap.h"

int main(int ac, char **av)
{
    Actions action;
    Stack *a;
    Stack *b;
    t_important *data;
    
    if(ac < 2)
        return (-1);
    data = malloc(sizeof(*data));
    stack_nums_counter(av, data);
    collect(av, data);
    __check__collection(data);
    __collecting_ints(data);
    action = init();
    a = malloc(sizeof(*a));
    b = malloc(sizeof(*b));
    store(&a, data);
    __sort_a__(&a, &b, data, action);
    return (0);
}
```

Sorting Function In where i do someting:
Input

> 4->1->0->2->3

```
#include "../includes/header_push_swap.h"

void __sort_a__(Stack **a, Stack **b, t_important *data, Actions action)
{
  action.ra(a);
   while((*a) != NULL)
   {
      ft_printf("%d ", (*a)->n);
      *a = (*a)->next;
   }
}
```

Output

> 1->0->2->3->0->4

Rotate Function:

```
void ra(Stack **a)
{
    Stack *first = *a;
    Stack *last = *a;
    if(check_stack_length(*a) <= 1)
        return ;
    while(last->next != NULL)
        last = last->next;
    *a = first->next;
    first->next = NULL;
    last->next = first;
}
```

Comment: `action.ra(a);`? What does that do? What's the definition of all the things you've shown? Please show a [mre].

Comment: Have you tried printing the list before this "rotate". I suspect that trailing '0' is already there...

Comment: Is your code really C?  The `action.ra(a)` *could* be valid C, but it seems more likely a sign that your code is C++.

Comment: @Fe2O3 I don't know about that. I can give my github page if you can tell me my problem i will be very grateful to you. 
[Github](https://github.com/davitmartirosyan/42-yerevan-push-swap)

Comment: No thanks about going there. Edit the question and paste in the LL struct definition AND the code that initialises it. I'm not keen to go off site... Remember: "Minimum Reproducible Example"? (Include the source for your 'push()' function, too)

Comment: @JohnBollinger I created a struct for function pointers.

Comment: I get dizzy trying to figure out why you've complicated a simple LL with so many levels of indirection. Looks to me like `store()` is leaking memory... Why are you allocating AHEAD of the need to store a bit of data. There's your weird '0' (uninitialised value of 'n')...

Comment: @Fe2O3 I did not understand from where "0" inserted to may list?

Comment: @Davit In `main()` you `malloc()` the first (uninitialised) node in the list, then use `store()` to append a node to that list... That first node is giving you grief. Put `a->n = 42` after that first malloc() in main() and I expect the troublesome '0' will now appear as '42'...

Comment: @Fe2O3 No. Nothing was changed. I wrote after the malloc a->n = 42 and then move the stack a to store. But when i print out the output is same that before. After all numbers prints "0"

Answer (score 0):

Your code to rotate the list seems correct. Yet the code to print the list is somewhat disturbing: why do you modify `*a`? You should just use a `Stack` pointer and follow the links.

Modify your program to print the list before and after the rotation using this modified version:

```
void rotate_stack(Stack **a) {
    Stack *first = *a;
    Stack *last = first;
    if (first != NULL && first->next != NULL) {
        while (last->next != NULL)
            last = last->next;
        *a = first->next;
        first->next = NULL;
        last->next = first;
    }
}

void print_stack(const Stack *s) {
    while (s != NULL) {
        ft_printf("%d ", s->n);
        s = s->next;
    }
    ft_printf("\n");
}

int main() {
    Stack *s = NULL;
    // construct the stack
    [...]
    print_stack(s);
    rotate_stack(&s);
    print_stack(s);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I Changed my code for more better visualize a problem. Please look at this code.

Comment: @Davit: it is bad practice to start your function or variable names with `__`. These identifiers are reserved for the compiler.

Comment: @Davit: Please post a complete compilable program (including `#include` lines) that displays the problem. There are too many pieces missing to investigate the issue.

Comment: @Davit: sorting a list should take at most 2 functions. Your naming conventions are quite obscure. Did your school suggest using `__` prefixes? Are you studying at *42* or _Epit***_?

Comment: I am study in 42 school :)

Comment: @Davit: you can accept this answer by clicking on the grey checkmark below its score.